# Lightweight JMS Selector Alternative

Tags: java, queue, jms, message-queue

i am looking for a lightweight queueing alternative to JMS (no extra server, i do not need to access it outside of my vm) that supports the same features like JMS-Selectors.

i want to have multiple consumers with different selectors that should all consume from the same queue.

for example i have message-properties like

{
  a : true, b : true
}

and consumers that use a selector for one of these. Does anyone know a library that meets my requirements or can hint me to a solution

Answer (score 1):

You can use JMS provider in embedded mode. It will start in the same VM you application is running. We are using HornertQ and it is not heavy in embedded mode.
Also you will have all the features of JMS (persistence, selectors, bridges etc.)